# Parameter limit on Callable statement - Oracle jdbc driver (oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver)

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, messagebroker

I am using IBM message broker, v8.0.0.2. I am trying to call a stored procedure with 45 parameters, in and out. I use the Oracle jdbc driver (oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver). Turns out that I get an 'Invalid column index' SqlException, whenever I try to set the 45th IN or OUT parameter, which is weird. Is there such a limit?

Comment: Can you please show your code and the complete error message/stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Give Us the Code you've created and the Exception from the Exception list, by the way ,test the stored procedure using SQL Developer or any editor you are using then.. create procedure using ESQL and Call Database Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedureName(IN PARAM1 TYPE, IN PARAM2 TYPE,...,
OUT PARAM44 TYPE, INOUT PARAM45 TYPE) 
LANGUAGE DATABASE DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 EXTERNAL NAME "ProcedureNameInDB";
```

In Main Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
   --CopyMessageHeaders();
   --CopyEntireMessage();

   -- DECLARE HERE PARAMETERS FOR THE PROCEUDRE
   -- In This Block Declare the 45 parameters for passing them in ESQL Procedure.
   -- Then ESQL will pass them to Oracle Stored Procedure.
   -- END DECLARE  PARAMETERS FOR THE PROCEUDRE

   -- Environment.DBRowSetResult: Storing Stored Procedure Output in Environment variable.

   CALL YourProcedureName(param1, param2, .... param44,param45, Environment.DBRowSetResult);

END;
```